# Angular: Component declared in app.module.ts not found in other components

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-components

I have a custom modal I want to reuse in a couple of other components. But as a compnent it's not found.

Getting:

```
NG0304: 'app-addtoplanner' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-addtoplanner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-addtoplanner' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I have registered the component in app.module in two ways in the base/root app.module:
1. as with the component in "declarations: [ ]" and 
2. I have also tried making a module all for itself and registering in "imports: [ ]" instead.

Either way it's not available.

I haven't included a reference to it in the child components (either the component or the sub-module) other than its selector in a template.

I can use it on a single child component when adding to that components own module so I know it's working. But not able to reuse (which is annoying as its a basic tenant of Angular, lol)

Any advice?

ps. The contents of my module from point 2 is below:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AddToPlannerComponent } from './add-to-planner/add-to-planner.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
  AddToPlannerComponent
  ],
 exports:
  [
    AddToPlannerComponent,
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class AddToPlannerModule { }
```

which is imported in my app.module

```
import {AddToPlannerModule} from './views/planner/add-to-planner.module'

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      AddToPlannerModule,
...
```

Comment: are you importing it into another module or same module ?

Comment: Exporting from the above module suitably buried in the directory tree into the root app.module

Answer (score 0):

If the component is declared in another module, you'll have to export it also.